Loading Related Table Data using Prisma
I'm using MySQL as the underlying database with Prisma ORM. I have two existing tables: candidates and skills. They are not connected (No relation table. Also, the skills table does not have any candidate_id field). The only link these two tables have is the primary_skills column in the candidates' table.  primary_skills column (JSON type) holds the array of ids (skill ids), for example: [34, 87, ..., 96].
I want to get the skills data when I query the candidates' table instead of just skill ids in the primary_skills field. For example:
{
    candidate_id: 1,
    primary_skills: [
        {
            id: 1,
            skill_name: "Dummy skill 1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            skill_name: "Dummy skill 2"
        }
    ],
    ...
    ...
}

Instead of:
{
    candidate_id: 1,
    primary_skills: [1, 2],
    ...
    ...
}

Is there any approach other than creating explicit/implicit many-to-many relationship? (Then I need to face huge migration of data as these are existing tables)

If you are using a relational database, then why don't you model many-to-many relationships as they are supposed to in a relational database through the use of a junction table?

Like the above commenter said, you really should be using your relational DB as intended and utilizing a junction table. If not, you're also missing out on advantages of Prisma. Bite the bullet and do the migration: this will make future development way easier.
